# Where to find the recievers modules on dji series?

Tags: dji

I'm searching for the receiver model inside the next small drones:

dji air 2S

dji mavic 2 pro

dji mavic 2 Zoom

dji mini 2

dji mavic 3

I searched all over the internet but did not find the receiver models.

Would appreciate help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure DJI designs all their own components, so there aren't usually individual receiver modules in the drones, because it saves weight to combine them onto the main board.

Answer (score 3):

The DJI receivers are not separate modules in these drones.

For example, internal images of the Mavic 2 Pro are available [here](https://fccid.io/SS3-L1P1805/Internal-Photos/Internal-Photos-3974337); in the bottom image on page 5 of the PDF, you can see the two U.FL antenna connectors on the top-left of the PCB. The transceiver electronics appear to be under the adjacent metal can. I've marked these on the image below:
[image: Mavic 2 Pro PCB]

Even if you were able to identify part numbers from the board, the firmware and communications protocols are almost certainly proprietary and encrypted.